# POSTGRES～DBLINKでシーケンスを取得したい

Tags: sql, postgresql

postgresを使用しています。
現在のシーケンス取得SQLは下記の状態になっています。

```html
select nextval('seq_no')
```

そして、'seq_no'(シーケンス)をDBLINKで取得するようにしたいのですが、方法がわからず調査中です。
・調査一覧
-select seq1.nextval from dual;→オラクルのみ

解決方法の分かる方がいましたらご教授をお願いします。

また、出来ればnextval内を修正するだけにとどめたいのですが、不可能でしたらSQL文自体を改変する回答でも大丈夫です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

改変する場合

```html
SELECT
*
FROM
  DBLINK( 
    'dbname=db host=123 user=postgres password=postgres'
    , 'select nextval(''seq_no'')'
  ) AS T( 
    seq_no int
  );
```

これでnextvalした後のシーケンス値を取得することが出来る。